# What does .and() do in Spring Security classes like HttpSecurity?

Tags: java, spring-security

In the below code example, what is the `.and()` actually doing?

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .addFilterAfter(new CsrfCookieGeneratorFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
            .rememberMe()
            .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices)
            .key(env.getProperty("jhipster.security.rememberme.key"))
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/api/authentication")
            .successHandler(ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
            .failureHandler(ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler)
            .usernameParameter("j_username")
            .passwordParameter("j_password")
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/logs/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/api/subscriptions").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
}
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/) :

> **The Java Configuration equivalent of closing an XML tag is expressed
>   using the and() method which allows us to continue configuring the
>   parent**. If you read the code it also makes sense. I want to configure
>   authorized requests and configure form login and configure HTTP Basic
>   authentication.

So consider you have multiple configuration one for users which have **admin** role, and the second for the **simple user** role, to concatenate all them together we use `and()` method.

And this technique is a [builder design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)

Comment: Thank You so much. I got it

Comment: 15 years of Java development and I can't even find the "and" method in the official documentation.

Comment: @Chuck check [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/SecurityConfigurerAdapter.html) in fact this method exist in many classes, one of them is what I share